# Preserve old version of product during major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

guys,

I have the following case: I want during the major upgrade to preserve the version of the product being upgraded (e.g. if I am upgrading from 1.1 to 1.2, to save the value 1.1) and to run an executable passing this version as a parameter, after the install of the new product finishes. This will mean that I will call this somewhere around `InstallFinalize`. I found this very helpful article for my case: http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx

The problem that I experience is that I don't know and can't find an explanation on when will the property be set. When will this registry search be executed. Am I going to set this property once on the start of the upgrade or is it going to be set dynamically when the property is being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the WiX major upgrade element, this should work with AllowDowngrades set to yes. There's no need to manually try to set a version somehow. See here:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html

where it says "AllowDowngrades already allows two products with the same version number to upgrade each other."

Definitely try this before trying to run code. Note that the ProductVersion property isn't "set" - it's in the MSI file and is transferred to the system from there.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have the following:
   `<Property Id="PRODUCT_VERSION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="Reg_SetProductVersion" Root="HKLM"
                      Key="$(var.ProductRegistryKey)"
                      Name="ProductVersion" Type="raw"/>
   </Property>` PRODUCT_VERSION will have my old product's version?

Comment: I can't tell because the actual values matter. You just need a WiX major upgrade element with allow downgrades, apart from that your new MSI is identical except for new ProductCode and PackageCode plus whatever files you changed.

Comment: The old version is 1.0.0 and the new one is 1.1.0.

Comment: Your original post says, quote "if I am upgrading from 1.1 to 1.2, to save the value 1.1) " so I'm just confused now. Either way, AllowDowngrades should allow to replace any version with the same version, which I believe was the question.

Comment: The version is not the problem. The problem is that I want to get the old version(of the currently installed application) and set it to a property. I am using the following:     `<Property Id="OLD_VERSION_PROPERTY">
      <RegistrySearch Id="Reg_SetAppDataDirr" Root="HKLM"
                      Key="$(var.ProductRegistryKey)"
                      Name="ProductVersion" Type="raw"/>
 </Property>
 
 <SetProperty Id="OLD_VERSION" Before="FindRelatedProducts" Value="..[OLD_VERSION_PROPERTY]" />` But, when I get the property in my custom action it is always the new version and not the old one.